# Is Block Height 1 is the genesis block?

Tags: development, altcoin

As the question I asked before, I wanted to make an altcoin. The block height in main.cpp allows you to choose which block gets different rewards. If it does, do txNew.vout[0].nValue =  depend on the first block or the normal block reward

Answer (score 2):

The genesis block has height 0 (at least in the Bitcoin reference client source code).